# Getting error when trying to retrieve a security Descriptor from a Win32_Service class

Tags: windows, security, powershell

I'm trying to retrieve the security descriptor of a Win32 Service. For that, I'm doing, in PowerShell,

```
$sd = (Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Service | ?{$_.Name -like "dummyservice"}).GetSecurityDescriptor()
```

Thing is, `$sd.Descriptor` is $null, and `$sd.ReturnValue` is `0x80070522`, which translates to *"a required privilege is not held by the client"*

I'm running all this in an admin session in a admin PS prompt. I tried both on Win 7 and Win 2008, same result.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

(Some context: I need to retrieve a security descriptor of a service to add some rights for a user to be able to start that service, then reassign that security descriptor back.)

Answer (score -1):

try this

((Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Service | ?{$_.Name -like "dummyservice"})).GetSecurityDescriptor()

Comment: why would that be different than my original expression??

Comment: when I run your code I get the same error when I run my code no error. In other words you got your objects screwed up.

Comment: @ariel can you remove the down vote please.